# How to change a list by its list length within a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, replace, numeric

I want the example_df in a wide format where each row represents a cell type, and where each column represents a receptor.

So far, using pivot_wider(), I created a dataframe called example_df_wider... But I want to change <dbl [2]>  to 2, and  to 0.

I'm quite new to R and programming... So, how can I do that?

Many thanks in advance!

```
example_df <- data.frame(cell_type=as.factor(c("cell_1","cell_1","cell_2","cell_2")),
           receptor = c("receptor_1","receptor_1", "receptor_2", "receptor_2"))
example_df

example_df_wider <- example_df %>% mutate(count=1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = receptor, values_from = count) 
example_df_wider
```

Comment: Welcome to SO (and programming). Can you read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and add a minimal reproducible example of you data? That will help others to help you.

Comment: You can perhaps try `unnest` to transform the column into a numeric variable, but without knowing what your data is, what code got you there, and what you are trying to achieve, that's about all anyone can say here. Please do read the link that Markus shared if you want to get a helpful answer.

Comment: @markus & Allan Cameron, thank you for your suggestions! I tried to create a minimal reproducible example :) (and I also tried out unnest(), but without success ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unlist the lists in the context of the dataframe you have to decide if you want them in a *long* or *wide* format, e.g.

##### Data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(CADM1 = c(list(c(12, 34, 2)), list(c(1, 2)),
        list(c(12, 34, 2, 33)), list(c(2))))

df
# A tibble: 4 × 1
  CADM1    
  <list>   
1 <dbl [3]>
2 <dbl [2]>
3 <dbl [4]>
4 <dbl [1]>
```

long format

```
df %>% 
  unnest(CADM1)
# A tibble: 10 × 1
   CADM1
   <dbl>
 1    12
 2    34
 3     2
 4     1
 5     2
 6    12
 7    34
 8     2
 9    33
10     2
```

wide format (needs to introduce `NA`s to pad the length of each list)

```
df %>% 
  unnest_wider(CADM1, names_sep="_")
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  CADM1_1 CADM1_2 CADM1_3 CADM1_4
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1      12      34       2      NA
2       1       2      NA      NA
3      12      34       2      33
4       2      NA      NA      NA
```

##### provided data

Using your example (I replaced `NULL` with `NA` because `NULL` brings some special behavior with it...)

```
example_df_wider$receptor_1[2] <- NA
example_df_wider$receptor_2[1] <- NA

example_df_wider
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  cell_type receptor_1 receptor_2
  <fct>     <list>     <list>    
1 cell_1    <dbl [2]>  <lgl [1]> 
2 cell_2    <lgl [1]>  <dbl [2]>
```

long format

```
example_df_wider %>% 
  unnest(starts_with("rec"))
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  cell_type receptor_1 receptor_2
  <fct>          <dbl>      <dbl>
1 cell_1             1         NA
2 cell_1             1         NA
3 cell_2            NA          1
4 cell_2            NA          1
```

wide format

```
example_df_wider %>% 
  unnest_wider(receptor_1, names_sep="_") %>% 
  unnest_wider(receptor_2, names_sep="_")
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  cell_type receptor_1_1 receptor_1_2 receptor_2_1 receptor_2_2
  <fct>            <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 cell_1               1            1           NA           NA
2 cell_2              NA           NA            1            1
```

Sum the values

```
example_df_wider %>% 
  unnest(starts_with("rec")) %>% 
  group_by(cell_type) %>% 
  summarize(across(starts_with("rec"), ~ sum(.x, na.rm=T)))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  cell_type receptor_1 receptor_2
  <fct>          <dbl>      <dbl>
1 cell_1             2          0
2 cell_2             0          2
```

Comment: Big thanks, sir! How can I sum the receptor values, instead of creating new columns like receptor_1_2? So that I get a dataframe of two rows (cell_1 and cel_2), but only 2 columns (receptor_1 and receptor_2) where the first row of receptor_1 contains the value 2?

Comment: @moltie See edit. You can sum the values by grouping and passing them to `summarize`.